# Visual Studio 2010 - Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.VirtualTreeGrid'

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I allowed Windows automatic updates to run today and suddenly Visual Studio is broken: I can no longer run unit tests and when I try to check files into TFS I'm presented with the following cheery error message:

[image]

What gives?

Comment: Try reapplying VS 2010 SP1 and restart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When all was said and done I had to wipe my computer and reinstall Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Look like something went wrong during the update, you can try to :

1. Reapply the given update (if you identified it).
2. Repair Visual Studio.